# How to solve error with python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

When the program executes the code

```
url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
```

I got some mistakes

> site-packages/social/utils.py", line 8, in
>
> [Wed Jul 01 19:01:02 2015] 
>   [error] [client 5.254.65.101:9114] import six
>
> [Wed Jul 01 19:01:02 2015] [error] [client 5.254.65.101:9114] ImportError: No module named six

But I have module six and can run:

```
import six
```

library python-social-auth was installed with  `pip install`

All settings copied from  [sample](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/examples/django_example/example/settings.py)

Dont use virtualenv, all was installed globally

Output of pip freeze comand

```
    Cython==0.22 
Django==1.8.2  
GnuPGInterface==0.3.2  
IPy==0.83
Jinja2==2.7.3 
MarkupSafe==0.23  
MySQL-python==1.2.3  
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==2.8.1  
PyJWT==1.3.0  
PyYAML==3.11  
apt-xapian-index==0.44
argparse==1.2.1  
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2 
chardet==2.0.1 
command-not-found==0.2.44  
FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package: 
distribute==0.6.24dev-r0
django-ajax-selects==1.3.6  
django-jinja==1.4.1
django-social-auth==0.7.28 
django-vkontakte-iframe==0.4.1
docker-compose==1.2.0rc2  
docker-py==1.1.0  
dockerpty==0.3.2
docopt==0.6.2  
httplib2==0.9.1  
iotop==0.4.4  
language-selector==0.1
marisa-trie==0.7  
oauth2==1.5.211  
oauthlib==0.7.2 
prettytable==0.7.2 
psutil==1.1.3  
pyCLI==2.0.3  
pycurl==7.19.0 
pylibacl==0.5.2 
pyroute2==0.2.16  
python-apt==0.8.3 ubuntu7.3
python-debian==0.1.21 
ubuntu1 python-openid==2.2.5
python-ptrace==0.8.1 
python-social-auth==0.2.11 
redis==2.10.3   
requests==2.5.3 
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0 
rfoo==1.3.0.1   
setproctitle==1.1.8 
six==1.9.0 
texttable==0.8.3 
ufw==0.31.1-1   
virtualenv==1.7.1.2 
websocket-client==0.29.0 
wsgiref==0.1.2   
xmpppy==0.5.0rc1
```

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Can you give us the output of pip list?

Comment: It was installed globally. Output added to post

Comment: Did you notice this?
command-not-found==0.2.44  
FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:

Comment: Are you running the app from a virtualenv?

Comment: Install virtualenv, install python-social-auth inside invironment,
Output of freeze 
PyJWT==1.3.0
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.24
oauthlib==0.7.2
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.11
requests==2.7.0
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
But still have errors ImportError: No module named six

Answer (score 0):

### Solved.

1 - Install virtualenv
`pip install virtualenv`

2 - make directory for environment

```
mkdir venv
virtualenv --system-site-packages <venv_name>
```

system-site-packages --- let you added a lot of previous function from project

3 - install library again

```
 pip install python-social-auth
```

4 Then you need to add environment directory to wsgi file

```
sys.path.append('/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

TaDaaam, it Works